# cloudfront with identity origin access

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I created a cloudfront and enable 'Origin Identity Access' (https://d118u7nzjnyfk4.cloudfront.net/Mt+Etna+Italy.jpg) but everytime I access it via browser I get below error. I checked online and it seems I have to use signin request. I'm newbie here so I will appreciate if you can enlighten on how to do this.

Error:
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Comment: Replace the `+` with `%20` in your URL, and this link works perfectly. Or replace `+` with a single space (!?) (which the browser will replace with `%20`).  Please verify. There's a known issue here, but I'll need a bit of time to document it properly in an answer.

Comment: It works. Thank You!